# Check if a list is sorted or not in ml language

Tags: ml

i want to write program that can checked a list is sorted or not in ml language program but i am new at this language

i write the below code and seems it works

is there any tips i can use in my ml programing

> ml programming language

```
let issorted x = match x with 
[] -> true
| _::[] -> true
| _::_ -> issorted_helper (x);; 



let rec issorted_helper x = match x with
| [] -> true
| h::t ->
    if h > t
        false
    else
        issorted_helper(t);;
```

Comment: This is not a code writing service. Show effort and ask specific programming questions. See [ask] for more.

Answer (score 1):

That code is not only in OCaml, it's also wrong, so there's little point in translating it.

Write down a case analysis on the structure of the list;

- The empty list is sorted
- A list with one element is sorted
- A list with more than one element is sorted if its first two elements are in order, and the tail of the list is sorted.

Then you translate that to SML.